Identify which script in redis is currently running
I'm encountering an issue with my Magento 2 shop where Redis reports the following error:
BUSY Redis is busy running a script. You can only call SCRIPT KILL or SHUTDOWN NOSAVE. Process went away

Upon checking the logs, it appears that the culprit is consistently the same script:
2160643:M 04 Jun 2024 02:30:11.917 # Lua slow script detected: still in execution after 5098 milliseconds. You can try killing the script using the SCRIPT KILL command. Script SHA1 is: 6990147f5d1999b936dac3b6f7e5d2071908bcf3
2160643:M 05 Jun 2024 02:30:13.788 # Lua slow script detected: still in execution after 5064 milliseconds. You can try killing the script using the SCRIPT KILL command. Script SHA1 is: 6990147f5d1999b936dac3b6f7e5d2071908bcf3
2160643:M 05 Jun 2024 02:32:23.071 # Lua slow script detected: still in execution after 5793 milliseconds. You can try killing the script using the SCRIPT KILL command. Script SHA1 is: 6990147f5d1999b936dac3b6f7e5d2071908bcf3
2160643:M 05 Jun 2024 02:33:10.581 # Lua slow script detected: still in execution after 7518 milliseconds. You can try killing the script using the SCRIPT KILL command. Script SHA1 is: 6990147f5d1999b936dac3b6f7e5d2071908bcf3
2160643:M 06 Jun 2024 02:30:13.565 # Lua slow script detected: still in execution after 5954 milliseconds. You can try killing the script using the SCRIPT KILL command. Script SHA1 is: 6990147f5d1999b936dac3b6f7e5d2071908bcf3
2160643:M 06 Jun 2024 02:32:22.369 # Lua slow script detected: still in execution after 5985 milliseconds. You can try killing the script using the SCRIPT KILL command. Script SHA1 is: 6990147f5d1999b936dac3b6f7e5d2071908bcf3

Is there a way in Redis to determine where this script originates from? I suspect it's consistently the same script due to the identical SHA1 encryption.
Unfortunately, the magento2 backend cronjob page is not really helpful to debug aswell as the magento2 cron.log

You could take a look at the cron_schedule table in your magento database to find out if some job triggers at the same time ?
Take a look at your redis memory usage too ?
In a last chance you can use redis-cli monitor to see what's running during these errors.

I stopped cron and added every magento2 script to redis and checked via script exists sha1, if the hash matches or not - but felt like an overkill

Found it, just here https://github.com/colinmollenhour/Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis/blob/master/Cm/Cache/Backend/Redis.php#L59
use_lua is now set by default to 1
You could try disable it to workaround this issue
